# C++ Multi threaded socket operation with progress bar update

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, mfc

I have a MFC DLL that I am implementing. The main thread creates a progress bar (CProgressCtrl) and then starts a CWinThread to perform some socket operation. The idea is to have the main thread update the progress bar while the other thread performs sendto socket operation (data request) to request data. Here is the issue though, due to legacy implementation, the receive capability is done via overriding OnReceive function of CAsyncSocket. When OnReceive is called, the code simply copies the data into its own buffer and allow another function to process later.

Currently, the other thread that is doing the sendto operation (data request) is activity checking the buffer to see if the sequence number has been incremented. This all worked fine when the sendto operation is within the main thread (this means UI will freeze), but after I relocated the sendto operations to another thread, the OnReceive is no longer being called even when the data is sent from the other software(verified).

My question is that why is OnReceive not being called when the other side is clearly sending data? I understand this might not be the optimal design but due to legacy design, i would like to keep the current design.

Answer (score 0):

CASyncSocket is bound to the thread in which it is created. Only that thread can receive the OnReceive notification.

Comment: So in this case, does it mean I will need to rewrite a good portion of the code? Thanks

Comment: Can't say, since you have not explained which thread(s) create the CAsyncSocket object(s) and what types of threads they are. The simple rule is that everything related to one CAsyncSocket object must be in the same thread, and that thread must be derived from CWinThread. I.e., it must be a message processing thread.